# Vim 8 - Matlab/Octave: two consecutive comment characters cancel out the commenting highlight

Tags: matlab, vim, octave, vim-syntax-highlighting

In **Matlab/Octave** syntax mode, my previous version of Vim uses to interpret anything after a comment character (%) as a comment, so highlighting everything as a comment in the row.

In Vim 8, the syntax highlighting correctly interprets a row starting with a single comment character and a space as a commenting row, for instance:

```
% % my comment is correctly highlighted
```

Instead, when there are two comment characters at the beginning of the row, the syntax highlight cancels out, for instance:

```
%% my comment is not highlighted
```

How to fix this?

Comment: If you think this is a bug in the Matlab syntax script that ships with Vim, please contact its author; you find the email address in the header of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/matlab.vim`.

Comment: According to the [syntax script](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/matlab.vim#L65) lines starting with `%%` are of type `matlabCellComment` and link to the  `TODO` group

Answer (score 1):

It is marking it as a cell comment in the case of %% which is different from the standard % comment.

MATLAB calls %% a code section https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html

Comment: Yes you are right. However, if Vim does recognize the row as "code section", how to force its syntax coloring (now not highlighted)?